# get all data of listview by 5 column and more than 2 row

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listView by 5 column and more than 2 row...

I want to get all field and copy them in arrays.

For example if I have these listview:

`column1       column2     column3     column4     column5`

`data1         data2       data3       data4       data5`

`data6         data7       data8       data9       data10`

I want to have array like this:

```
array={data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,...,data10}
```

I tried :it dose not work because in this array is just **one column**

```
var myList = new List<string>();
        foreach (ListViewItem Item in listView2.Items)
        {
            myList.Add(Item.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I'm confused...can't you cast the list to an array? And if you want more columns you may have to make your own object and populate it there       'string[] = myList.ToArray();'

Answer (score 0):

ListViewItems is a list so you should use an index to get valued
your code should be like that:

```
var myList = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListViewItem Item in listView2.Items)
    {
       for ( int i = 0 ; i < item.Count ; i++ )
       {
            myList.Add(Item[i].ToString());
       }   

    }
```

This should normally help you.

Comment: thank you but this code has 2 errors: 1-Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group' 2-Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'